# React Native Navigation 5.0 bottomTabs - how to change the font size?

Tags: reactjs, navigation, native

is there a way to change the font size of the two "name" props below in React Native Navigation 5.0?

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Game" component={HomeStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Map" component={SettingsStackScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add tabBoarOptions to your code like this.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
          labelStyle: {
            fontSize: 10,
            fontFamily:'GothamBook'
           
          },>
    <Tab.Screen name="Game" component={HomeStackScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Map" component={SettingsStackScreen} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

);
};

Answer (score 0):

```
<Tab.Screen
    name="About"
    component={About}
    options={{
      headerShown: false,
      tabBarLabelStyle: {
        fontSize: 13,
      },
      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
        <AntDesign name="infocirlceo" size={24} color="black" />
      ),
    }}
  />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

resolved in issue #21. all good :)
https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-tab-navigator/issues/21